# How to sort items above 99?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I got a bit of JavaScript that sort divs on my website depending on whats the content in a span tag inside it.

It looks like this:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    var $divs = $("div.box");
    $('#numBnt').on('click', function () {
        var numericallyOrderedDivs = $divs.sort(function (a, b) {
            return $(a).find("span").text() < $(b).find("span").text();
        });
        $("#container").html(numericallyOrderedDivs);
    });
});
```

The only problem I got with it that when the numbers inside the Span tag gets above 99 it dosent order anymore, with other words it only orders numbers 0-99. is there any way I can get it order all numbers depending on how big they are?

Comment: Your comparison function is completely wrong. It's supposed to return a number, not true/false. it returns less than 0 if `a < b`, it returns greater than 0 if `a > b`, otherwise it returns 0.

Comment: [Your comparison function is invalid](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24080785/1048572).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the difference of numbers and return it. There is no need to parse the string, since [subtraction(`-`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Subtraction_(-)) automatically converts it to number.

```
$(window).load(function(){
    var $divs = $("div.box");        
    $('#numBnt').on('click', function () {

        var numericallyOrderedDivs = $divs.sort(function (a, b) {
            return $(b).find("span").text() - $(a).find("span").text();
        });

        $("#container").html(numericallyOrderedDivs);
    });
});
```

Comment: This works greate exept that now it sorts low->high and i want it to sort high->low? any way to fix that?

Comment: @AntonKihlström : glad to help :)